# Spring Upgrade cause issues dispatcherServletRegistration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, jersey

We are trying to upgrade Spring boot app from 1.5.9 to 2.2.7. We use the following Servlet Registrations in the app:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new DispatcherServlet());
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("org.atmosphere.servlet", "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet");
    params.put("contextClass", "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
    registration.setInitParameters(params);
    return registration;
}


@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean configureJerseyForRESTfulWebService() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/service/*");
    registration.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyConfig.class.getName());
    registration.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
    return registration;
}


@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean securityFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(new SecurityFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registration.setName("SecurityFilter");
    registration.setOrder(1);
    return registration;
}
```

After the upgrade, we are getting the following errors during startup and service unable to run:

```
Parameter 0 of method errorPageCustomizer in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath' that could not be found.



The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'dispatcherServletRegistration' in 'DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration' not loaded because DispatcherServlet Registration found servlet registration bean dispatcherServletRegistration

Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath' in your configuration.
```

Any hint how to resolve theses errors/issues. If possible please share any code example, thanks

Comment: Just a guess, but try to add a url-pattern for the DispatcherServlet

Comment: I did added the url-pattern, not working